# Java simple I/O server & client connection reset?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I started learning about networking, sockets three days ago, and I started understanding a few things after I moved to using eclipse IDE.

I managed to get the client to work, basically send the input to the server, but when I do so i get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

That's the full log of the server:

```
Server started.
Connected: /127.0.0.1:57276
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Server.run(Server.java:31)
    at Server.main(Server.java:22)
```

Line 31:

```
in = input.readLine();
```

Line 22:

```
run();
```

I am probably not reading the I/O correctly, I didn't really look at "many" examples, I tried to get it myself and learn from my errors.

Can someone explain what happens here? why does the connection reset?

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket socket;
    private static PrintWriter output;
    private static BufferedReader input;
    private static Socket socketClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server started.");
            socket = new ServerSocket(43537);
            socketClient = socket.accept();
            output = new PrintWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream());
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Connected: " + socketClient.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
            run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void run() throws IOException {
        String in;
        while (socketClient.isConnected()) {
             in = input.readLine();
            if (in != null) {
                System.out.println(in);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class build {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Client started");
            Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 43537);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (input != null) {
                out.print(input);
            }
            if (reader.toString() != null) {
                System.out.println(reader.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Client error");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client have written the data from kbd to socket and closed the socket by the time server tries to read message at line 31. Seems it's because you mistakenly did `reader.toString()` in client instead of `reader.readLine()`. `readLine()` will make client to stay online until response from server is received (or server is shut down).

In client you need to change to

```
        if (input != null) {
            out.println(input);
            out.flush();
        }
```

- `println()`, not `print()`, because you use `readLine()` on server side, which won't return until it sees `\n`;
- even with that you need `out.flush()` to send data to network;

Comment: That was the error, thank you!. But now the server won't print the value that the client sent, why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush() your streams, close() your streams and close() your sockets. You've been reading a crappy tutorial if it didn't teach you this.

> I am probably not reading the I/O correctly, I didn't really look at
>   "many" examples, I tried to get it myself and learn from my errors.

Maybe you should rethink your learning strategy.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java I don't really see close/flush here

Comment: That's horrible. Even though it's a simple example, leaving out the clean-up is an amateur mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your Client reads exactly one line of input, sends it to the server and then the program terminates thus closing the socket - which is what the error message says.